# YouTube Data API: PlaylistItems: list - snippet publishedAt Returning uploaded date instead of published date

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTubeAPI PlaylistItems: list to retrieve the most recent videos I've uploaded. Up until a week or so ago the playlistitems.item.snippet.publishedAt value returned the date the video was published. Now it appears this value is returning the date the video was uploaded. A video that was published yesterday shows it was published 8+ days ago when it was originally uploaded. This video (along with the others affected) were all uploaded on the same date, always set to private never unlisted and scheduled to be released on a specific date/time.

This is the response I'm getting from [https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUhi5MyXJLQuPni3dM19Ar3g&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUhi5MyXJLQuPni3dM19Ar3g&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "n7hGa6RMjI-sRVXU8hch13PdCDo",
  "nextPageToken": "EAAaBlBUOkNCNA",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "pGT_oiGswmjgJXqc1gh8nycNWQ4",
      "id": "VVVoaTVNeVhKTFF1UG5pM2RNMTlBcjNnLnlNaGZHaEJadF9j",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-01-24T20:29:06Z",
```

YouTube API website where you can "Try this API" I'm getting this response:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUhi5MyXJLQuPni3dM19Ar3g%22%7D

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "USoSirgO2XD5JSNHas4dzixQ1Q4",
  "nextPageToken": "EAAaBlBUOkNBVQ",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "pGT_oiGswmjgJXqc1gh8nycNWQ4",
      "id": "VVVoaTVNeVhKTFF1UG5pM2RNMTlBcjNnLnlNaGZHaEJadF9j",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-01-24T20:29:06Z",
```

Both of these values **now** are reporting the same and incorrect value. Earlier today when I testing this using Visual Studio and the website I was getting differing values. (see attached images)

[Visual Studio (incorrect publishedAt value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlLVb.png)
[YouTube Data API (correct publishedAt value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPtN9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) doesn't work properly (on my side too) however [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) seems to work fine (cf https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=yMhfGhBZt_c&key=KEY), since you can check up to 50 videos with a single request you will just double your workload and quota usage.

Comment: Doubling my Quote is not something I can do. I'm retrieving this information for around 26 channels once an hour. Doubling will exceed quota, unfortunately.

Comment: Then you might be interested in my [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/) which has an endpoint giving a more precise timestamp of when your playlist videos were published: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUhi5MyXJLQuPni3dM19Ar3g otherwise you can also use my free quota YouTube Data API v3 embedder: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUhi5MyXJLQuPni3dM19Ar3g and https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet&id=yMhfGhBZt_c

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got your question answered. my reading of the [resource json here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource)

the field you want would be `contentDetails.videoPublishedAt`